# DAX Measure to subtract value from oldest invoices

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a customer data consisting of customer name and their account balance split in time frames loaded from cube:
CUSTOMER, 0 days, 1-30 days, 31-60 days, 61-90, etc.
there is also a column with their debt amount.
I need to present a table with customers and their account balance in those time periods but modified by debt amount if exist in a way that debt amount is being subtracted form oldest balance first.

So, for example:

```
Customer    0 days    1-30 days    31-60 days    61-90 days
A           100$      150$         30$           200$
```

balance and the -300$ debt

and I need a measure which would return values:

```
Customer    0 days    1-30 days    31-60 days    61-90 days
A           100$      80$          0$            0$
```

I appreciate your help as always. Thank You in advance.

Comment: Please update your sample and expected data as I formatted the first one. This is for easy understanding :)

Comment: Can you now please explain logics for measures, I mean how values are changing?

Comment: So the Data table looks exactly like the first one, so there are period columns, and they store account balance for each customer in certain period. But the customer might have also some debt value which need to be subtracted form balance but oldest first. It's like with bills, if you'll pay some money, they will cover the oldest bills first.

Comment: Where is the entry for Debt?

Comment: debt value is in other table, can be either found by LOOKUPVALUE or I can merge queries and have it in this table. Let's assume that it just is stored in a VAR called Debt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For customer A debt, I have considered a measure as below-

```
customer_A_debt = 300
```

**Now** create this below 4 measures-

```
61-90 days new value = 

VAR remaining_debt = [customer_A_debt]

RETURN
IF(
    MIN(your_table_name[61-90 days]) <= remaining_debt,
    0,
    MIN(your_table_name[61-90 days]) - remaining_debt
)
```

```
31-60 days new value = 

VAR remaining_debt = 
IF(
    [customer_A_debt] - MIN(your_table_name[61-90 days]) <= 0,
    0,
    [customer_A_debt] - MIN(your_table_name[61-90 days])
)

RETURN
IF(
    MIN(your_table_name[31-60 days]) <= remaining_debt,
    0,
    MIN(your_table_name[31-60 days]) - remaining_debt
)
```

```
1-30 days new value = 

VAR remaining_debt = 
IF(
    [customer_A_debt] - (MIN(your_table_name[61-90 days]) + MIN(your_table_name[31-60 days])) <= 0,
    0,
    [customer_A_debt] - (MIN(your_table_name[61-90 days]) + MIN(your_table_name[31-60 days]))
)

RETURN
IF(
    MIN(your_table_name[1-30 days]) <= remaining_debt,
    0,
    MIN(your_table_name[1-30 days]) - remaining_debt
)
```

```
0 days new value = 

VAR remaining_debt = 
IF(
    [customer_A_debt] - (MIN(your_table_name[61-90 days]) + MIN(your_table_name[31-60 days]) + MIN(your_table_name[1-30 days])) <= 0,
    0,
    [customer_A_debt] - (MIN(your_table_name[61-90 days]) + MIN(your_table_name[31-60 days]) + MIN(your_table_name[1-30 days]))
)

RETURN
IF(
    MIN(your_table_name[0 days]) <= remaining_debt,
    0,
    MIN(your_table_name[0 days]) - remaining_debt
)
```

Here is the sample output-

[image]

Comment: Thank You, It was similar to my first thought. It's working. I will still try to experiment a little with creating table with names of columns containing time periods and indexing them from oldest to newest and try to use that to switch between different periods subtracting the debt value.